# Run sh file wiith ssh2_exec (PHP)

Tags: php, ssh, centos, sh

Im trying to run a sh file with ssh2_exec and getting stream data when it's done.

BTW im using CentOS.

But when im using `ssh2_exec('./file.sh');` for example nothing happned..

is it possible to get execute output when the file is done running?

Comment: From the [ssh2_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) man page. `ssh2_exec` returns a stream or false. So to get the output use [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per example from [PHP manual about ssh2_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php)

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
```

ssh2_exec() is used to pass a command to a shell session/connection.

In order to read the stream contents, you may try:

```
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
```

On the other hand, if you were looking to run a command on the php/host server, you could try with shell_exec:

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```